# Passing extra parameters to ASP.NET MVC controller action from jQuery Grid plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I am trying to use jQuery Grid plugin with ASP.NET MVC to display data. It seems examples provided on the web shows that the controller action signature looks like this:

```
public ActionResult SomeMethod(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows) { }
```

Is there any way I can pass extra parameters from various input fields on the page?

Cheers,
D.

ADDED: I have not written any code yet but the client side code will be something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
      jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
        url:'/Entry/GridData/',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',
        colNames:['Entry Date','Registration','Registered Name'],
        colModel :[
          {name:'EntryDate', index:'EntryDate', width:40 },
          {name:'Registration', index:'Registration', width:200 },
          {name:'RegisteredName', index:'RegisteredName', width:200 }],
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        rowNum:20,
        rowList:[5,10,20,50],
        altRows: true,
        sortable: false,
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: 'My first grid'
      }); 
    });
```

And the server side code something like:

```
public ActionResult GridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
{
    //Some stuff to get data, which needs a couple of extra parameters on top of the ones in the signature
    return Json(dataCollection);
}
```

In the GridData action I need a couple more parameters to get the appropriate data. How do I specify these in the javascript, and how do I get hold of them in the controller action?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the `postData` property:

```
$('#list').jqGrid({
    url: '@Url.Action("SomeMethod")',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST'
    postData: { 
        someParam1: $('#someInput1').val(),
        someParam2: $('#someInput2').val() 
    }
    ...
});
```

and in your controller action you could add this parameter:

```
public ActionResult SomeMethod(string someParam1, string someParam2, string sidx, ...) { }
```

Comment: Awesome! I saw the postData: property not long after I posted the question update. It looks promising, but I guess the mtype: property has to be set to 'POST'? or will this work with GET as well?

Comment: @DanyW, I think it will work also with GET but not 100% sure, haven't tested it. If it doesn't you could append to the url: `url: '@Url.Action("SomeMethod")?' + $.param({ someparam: 'some value' })`

Comment: Worked like a charm! It worked with GET too, as long as the return has JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet specified! I didn't need to append it to the url. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Create another action method that corresponds to the purpose of the particular input and accepts the arguments you want to accept.  If you need to get back to this action result at the end of processing the other result, call a RedirectToRoute

Comment: Sorry, I'm not entirely sure how that works. How do I include the extra data in the jQuery("#list").jqGrid({...}); call? And how do I pick it up in the controller action? Thanks.