# jqGrid not invoke the asp.net mvc controller action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

in my asp.net mvc, using jqGrid to bind the data. code is as below. But its not loading the data and not hitting the controller action when debugging. what's the problem in this below code. Alert is showing the url but not hitting the controller action. Help would be appreciate. Please let me know if you need more information

```
@model Stud.Areas.Admin.Models.AdminVM

@using Stud.Common.Extension;



<h2>MD Index</h2>


<br />
<div style="margin-top: -45px">


        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="gridDivmsg" style="clear: both;">
                <table id="jqGrid" ></table>
                <div id="jqGridPagermsg"></div>
            </div>
        </div>



</div>

@section scripts{

<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
@*<script src="~/Scripts/MDScript.js"></script>*@


    @Html.jqGridSetup()

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
                var $grid = $('#jqGrid');
            var $gridDiv = $('#gridDivmsg');

            function reloadGridmsg() {

                var urlName = '@Url.Action("GetMessagesForGrid", "MD")';

                $grid.jqGrid("setGridParam", { url: urlName, datatype: "json", page: 1 }).trigger("reloadGridmsg");
                $gridDiv.show();
                alert(urlName);
                }

            $grid.jqGrid({
                editurl: '@Url.Action("EditRowMessage")',
                datatype: 'local',
                styleUI: 'Bootstrap',
                colNames: ['Id', 'Message Key', 'Message Value', 'Message Status'],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 1, hidden: true, editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules: { required: true } },
                    { name: 'MessageKey', index: 'MessageKey', width: 1, editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules: { required: true } },
                    { name: 'MessageValue', index: 'MessageValue', width: 1, editable: true, edittype: 'textarea', editrules: { required: true } },
                    { name: 'MessageStatus', index: 'MessageStatus', width: 1, editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: { 'Active': 'Active', 'InActive': 'InActive' }, defaultValue: 'Active' }, editrules: { required: true } }
                ],
                responsive: true,
                loadonce: true,
                pager: $('#jqGridPagermsg'),
                height: 'auto',
                sortname: 'Id',
                rowNum: 20,
                autowidth: true,
                viewrecords: true,
                altRows: true,
                altclass: 'jqGridAltRow'
            });

            $grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', { autosearch: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn" });
            $grid.jqGrid('navGrid', "#jqGridPagermsg", {
                edit: true,
                add: true,
                del: false,
                search: false,
                refresh: false,
                view: false,
                position: "left",
                cloneToTop: false
            },
            {
                editCaption: "Edit User",
                recreateForm: true,
                checkOnUpdate: true,
                checkOnSubmit: true,
                closeAfterEdit: true,
                errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                    return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
                },
                afterComplete: function () {
                    reloadGridmsg();
                }
            },
            {
                addCaption: "Add User",
                closeAfterAdd: true,
                recreateForm: true,
                errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                    return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
                },
                afterComplete: function () {
                    reloadGridmsg();
                }
            },
            {
                errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                    return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
                }
            });

            reloadGridmsg();

        });


    </script>

}
```

Controller Action method is as below.

```
public ActionResult GetMessagesForGrid(StudVM model)
        {
            if (!IsAuthorized(Enums.Rights.Admin))
                return View("NoAccess");

            var gridData = _activityService.GetVCRMessagesList();

            int totalRecords = gridData.Count();
            int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)model.rows);
            var jsonData = new
            {
                total = totalPages,
                page = model.page,
                records = totalRecords,
                rows = gridData.Select(d => new { Id = d.Id, cell = new object[] {  d.Id, d.MessageKey, d.MessageValue, d.MessageStatus } }).ToArray()
            };
            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

till i'm getting blank grid as below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXTCx.png)

Comment: Check the developers tools console for any javascript or failed api calls.
 var urlName = '@Url.Action("GetMessagesForGrid", "MD")'; does this include controller name as well? I think url will only consists of action name.

Comment: I check the console in developer tools also...its error free.

Comment: Do you see any API call to your endpoint in Network tab of developer tools? Also what does alert(urlName); display?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is having a parameter `model` of type `StudVM` which is not passed in your javascript url.
Try passing parameter of type `StudVM`. It may resolve your issue.

```
$grid.jqGrid("setGridParam", { url: urlName,postData: { model:<your model>}, datatype: "json", page: 1 }).trigger("reloadGridmsg");
```

Comment: Hi Priyanka, thanks for your help.  GetMessagesForGrid is actionresult method...I'm calling that in jquery using Url.Action. Any possibility to pass model in Url.Action ? if so. please

Comment: i have updated code above please check once. you need to pass post data with your jqGrid

Comment: I tried by passing model...till grid is empty without data. My worry is it's not hitting the debugger point at actionresult of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the action method follow some method signature as follows

```
public ActionResult GetMessagesForGrid(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, bool _search, string filters)
        {
            if (!IsAuthorized(Enums.Rights.Admin))
                return View("NoAccess");

            var gridData = _activityService.GetVCRMessagesList();

            int totalRecords = gridData.Count();
            int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / rows);
            var jsonData = new
            {
                total = totalPages,
                page = page,
                records = totalRecords,
                rows = gridData.Select(d => new { Id = d.Id, cell = new object[] {  d.Id, d.MessageKey, d.MessageValue, d.MessageStatus } }).ToArray()
            };
            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I also don't see a reason why you don't make the grid datatype to json and specify the url in the begging when you define the grid instead of making the grid client side and then reloading it

```
 $grid.jqGrid({
                editurl: '@Url.Action("EditRowMessage")',
                datatype: 'json',
                 url: '@Url.Action("GetMessagesForGrid", "MD")'
                styleUI: 'Bootstrap',
                colNames: ['Id', 'Message Key', 'Message Value', 'Message Status'],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 1, hidden: true, editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules: { required: true } },
                    { name: 'MessageKey', index: 'MessageKey', width: 1, editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules: { required: true } },
                    { name: 'MessageValue', index: 'MessageValue', width: 1, editable: true, edittype: 'textarea', editrules: { required: true } },
                    { name: 'MessageStatus', index: 'MessageStatus', width: 1, editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: { 'Active': 'Active', 'InActive': 'InActive' }, defaultValue: 'Active' }, editrules: { required: true } }
                ],
                responsive: true,
                // loadonce: true,
                pager: $('#jqGridPagermsg'),
                height: 'auto',
                sortname: 'Id',
                rowNum: 20,
                autowidth: true,
                viewrecords: true,
                altRows: true,
                altclass: 'jqGridAltRow'
            });
```

if you need to know how to make that action method custom look at 
 [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983169/passing-extra-parameters-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-action-from-jquery-grid-plugi)